# Calling functions from a shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm trying to call a "core" function from a shared library's function but I get:

```
./a.out: symbol lookup error: ./libtest.so: undefined symbol: testf
```

The code I'm using is very basic because I'm just getting into writing shared libraries and it's just for testing purposes:
main.h

```
extern void testf();
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern void testf()
{
    printf("bla bla\n");
}

int main () {

void *handle = NULL;
void (*testlib)(void) = NULL;

handle = dlopen("./libtest.so" ,RTLD_LAZY);
testlib = dlsym(handle, "testfunc");

if ( testlib == NULL ) 
{
    printf("Error: %s \n", dlerror());
}
else 
{
    testlib();
}
}
```

libtest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

void testfunc() {

printf("Test plugin\n");
testf();
}
```

And the commands I compile it with:

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall libtest.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.1 -o libtest.so libtest.o -lc
gcc main.c -ldl
```

Is it possible to achieve this? Tried to find the answer, but don't really know how to form the question right so I can search better for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, managed to find the answer:
I was compiling the main program with wrong parameters, should use:

```
gcc main.c -ldl -rdynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are trying to call a function of a executable from the library. I think you actually required reverse of this.

Comment: I am trying to call the function testf() from inside the library and I want the testf() function to be defined outside of the library that calls it.

Comment: then go for another library