# Callback functions in C++ dynamic linked library

Tags: c++, function, callback

I have a dynamic linked library in C++. What I want to do is have a callback function declared in the library and leave it to the user to define in their code that uses the library. Pseudo-code example:

```
//in library
void userDefinedFunction();

void libraryFunction() {
    //do stuff
    userDefinedFunction();
    //do more stuff
}
```

```
//in user code
void userDefinedFunction() {
    //user-specific code
}
```

Is this possible in modern C++?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485074/calling-functions-from-a-shared-library

Comment: Thanks for the link! That person seems to be trying to do exactly the same thing as I am, but I forgot to mention I'm on Mac OS (sorry!) with Xcode (clang) and Google says I shouldn't need -rdynamic. (I tried it anyway and still got an undefined userDefinedFunction...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Your library could accept a function pointer to a user defined function or a reference to a functor given by the user. The void libraryFunction() will just use that to call the user function.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I tried the function pointer method, but my library doesn't seem to "see" the function assignment. I added `void (*userDefinedFunction)();` to the library .h, and then in my main.cpp I have `userDefinedFunction=someNewFunction; userDefinedFunction();`, which works—however, in the next line libraryFunction() is called, and within its scope userDefinedFunction appears to be null. I'm sure it must be something trivial and I feel kind of stupid, but I have no idea as to why that would be...

Comment: @arghhh Because the function pointer void (*userDefinedFunction) has not been set within the library. You just set it in the main. The library version does not know about it. Put a void SetFunction(int (*func)(int) f) { userDefinedFunction = f; } in the library and use that to set it within the library.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the clarification! I'm marking your answer as accepted because it's what I ended up going with, but I suppose your comment would work just as well for Bouraoui Al-Moez L.A's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::function` from functional library. Here is an example with lambda expression and function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

 std::function<int (int)> func;

int testfunc(int i)
{
    std::cout<<"testfunc function called "; 
    return i+7; 

}

void process()
{
    if (func)
        std::cout<<func(3)<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    process();
    func = [](int i) { 
        std::cout<<"Lambda function called "; 
        return i+4; 
    };
    process();
    func = testfunc;
    process();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and example! The example helped a lot! I tried it but got the same results as with stackoverblown's answer (function is defined in int main(), but undefined in libraryFunction()). Maybe I'm compiling/linking something wrong? (I'm on Xcode 11 on Mac OS by the way)